# Connecting phpMyAdmin to a MySQL server over SSL

Tags: mysql, ssl, phpmyadmin, ssl-certificate

I may be barking up the wrong tree... However, what I have is a MySQL server that accepts connections only from a client with a valid SSL cert (see [this link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/secure-create-certs.html)). This works great for example with Rails. I have my database on one server, and a Rails app that connects using the client certificate. Maybe not the fastest, but it works.

The configuration in **database.yml** looks something like this:

```
sslkey: /path/to/client-key.pem
sslcert: /path/to/client-cert.pem
sslca: /path/to/ca-cert.pem
```

The problem is that I'd like to host phpMyAdmin on the same server as the Rails app. I think that phpMyAdmin is simply more limited in its connection options because I can't seem to find a way for it to use a client certificate to connect. But what I found odd was that Googling for answers didn't turn up much on this subject (which makes me wonder if I'm taking the wrong approach to this).

Obviously, I can easily set up phpMyAdmin itself to be hosted behind an SSL certificate (which will encrypt requests between the client browser and my phpMyAdmin server) but I want the phpMyAdmin <-> db connection to be encrypted as well.

Is this possible? Is this a bad design choice? Are there better ways to do this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

in your `config.inc.php` add this line after applicable server stuff:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl']=true;
```

Assuming your php and its mysql client is configured with SSL in mind this should work.

Comment: While this does seem to enable SSL, it doesn't seem to do anything for certificate-based authentication.

Comment: are you sure that you can do SSL connection through PHP? Keep in mind that my.cnf used by CL mysql might not be the same used by PHP. I would recommend writing a quick test script with forced encryption to make sure its working.

Comment: A [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away) is likely something wrong with SSL config.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that the fully comprehensive answer is well explained in PHPmyadmin doc:
https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#example-google-ssl

You shall follow it and configure your server connection record in config.inc.php as follows:

```
// IP address of your instance
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '8.8.8.8';
// Use SSL for connection
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl'] = true;
// Client secret key
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_key'] = '../client-key.pem';
// Client certificate
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_cert'] = '../client-cert.pem';
// Server certification authority
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_ca'] = '../server-ca.pem';
// Disable SSL verification (see above note)
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['ssl_verify'] = false;
```

Comment: And what if `ssl_cert` and `ssl_ca` are in the same file? I mean Let's Encrypt generates a `fullchain.pem` which includes both of them in a single file

Answer (score 2):

I agree, the answer is not sufficient.  The place everybody tells you to put your SSL certificate and pointer is in a `conf.d` virtualhost block.  But that is for inbound traffic.  Only if your `phpmyadmin` is being accessed from the IP address of the mysql server but that is NOT the case with this example. Here we are using `phpmyadmin` to go out and make a REMOTE request to a REMOTE server from a local machine.

In order to do it, `phpmyadmin` must have a config setting to allow specification of where the `cert` files are.  Otherwise, I don't see how this will work. Although maybe the virtualhost block will work for outgoing traffic too. I suppose we can try ... My thoughts are that virtualhost works only for INBOUND traffic.