# Back up a table with a GEOMETRY column using mysqldump?

Tags: mysql, geometry

I recently created a MySQL table with a column of type GEOMETRY.

When I back up the table with mysqldump, it outputs my geometry column as a quoted string, containing some escaped characters like \0, and also some characters that look like raw binary bytes in the upper-ASCII range.

When I try to restore the dump to another database it fails with an error:

"Cannot get GEOMETRY object from the data you send to the Geometry field".

I tried adding --hex-blob to my command line but this does not change the output or fix the problem.

I'm sure someone didn't create a data type in MySQL and forget to include a way to back it up. What am I missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, this error appeared specifically with **empty** geometry values in a non-null geometry column.

In my case, the empty geometries were legitimate cases of unknown geometry, so I addressed this by changing the column to allow null values, and then running `UPDATE ... SET geom = NULL WHERE IsEmpty(geom);`

After this, I was able to re-run `mysqldump` and successfully import the resulting sql into a separate database.

(To be honest, I'm not sure how the empty geometry values got there in the first place - I don't even know the syntax to create an empty geometry value)

Answer (score 3):

Frank, this appears to be a long-standing (and still open) bug with mysqldump.   See http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43544.

As a workaround, you may be able to use the ogr2ogr tool to export the data to a shapefile, and then import it back into the database.  See http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm that this problem doesn't occur when using the Export / Import Data functions in MySQL Workbench. http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Answer (score 2):

in my case, it was because the GEOMETRY dumped as a `binary_ 'XXX'`, in that case I re-dump it using `mysqldump --hex-blob` and then I can retore it without any issue

Answer (score 0):

Recently encountered what appeared on the surface to be this exact issue.  Exporting using mysqldump from version 5.7.33 and importing using SQL Workbench into a fresh version 5.7.33 database.  In my case the error message was identical but it related to a column of type `POINT`.

Eventually identified that the source file had been amended using [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) which had partially and subtly scrambled the `_binary 'zzzzzz'` values.

Answer (score -2):

I once faced this issue but manage to passthrough by using gzip. Please check my sample commands:
**Export:**

```
mysqldump -u root -p db_name | gzip > dump.sql.gz
```

**Import:**

```
pv dump.sql.gz | gunzip | mysql -u root -p other_db
```

Comment: And why would gzip/gunzip help?

Comment: I confirm that it was *useless* in my case