# Backup in Mysql periodically

Tags: mysql, geometry, gis, database-backups

I have trouble scheduling a backup in mysql periodically, most of the tools do not recognize the geometric field, for example navicat which says

> Can not get geometry object from data you send to the GEOMETRY field

others simply do not create the table or do not fill the field with the information, someone knows a solution that is free and effective for this problem

Comment: You should be more explicit about what requirements you have. Would a simple `mysqldump` suite your needs?

Comment: This would be better asked on [dba.se]

Comment: The requirements are simple, I need a backup periodically schedule a mysql database that contains a table with a geometric field, the database is in windows version of mysql is 5.5.25, the problem is that all I find options to generate program the dump me out mistakes or simply ignore the field

Answer (score 1):

correct dump:

- geometry tables don't get dumped correctly without --hex-blob
- also to get functions and triggers use --routines --triggers

  mysqldump --hex-blob --routines --triggers -u root -p mydbname > dumped.sql

Answer (score 0):

Backing up spatial data in MySQL is difficult.  See [Back up a table with a GEOMETRY column using mysqldump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17480559/back-up-a-table-with-a-geometry-column-using-mysqldump) for problems specific to mysqldump.   One solution others have been able to implement is use a tool like [ogr2ogr](http://www.bostongis.com/PrinterFriendly.aspx?content_name=ogr_cheatsheet) to dump the data as shapefiles and then reimport the shapefiles into the database as needed.