# how to import the .sql file having size 150MB from terminal or phpmyadmin

Tags: php, database, file-upload, mysql

I am trying the upload the .sql file having size `150MB` using terminal or phpmyadmin but giving the errors

this is what I did before the importing the file

in `php.ini` file

```
1)post_max_size = 20000M
2)upload_max_filesize = 20000M
3)max_execution_time = 50000
4)max_input_time = 50000
5)memory_limit = 20000M
```

& 
in /etc/mysql/my.cn

```
6)max_allowed_packet = 2G
```

& in the /usr/share/phpmyadmin/libraries/config.defalut.php

```
 $cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] = '0'; //to make it unlimited, this was 300 default
```

even after these many setting I am getting errors:
when tried from the terminal as

```
 mysql -u root -p dbname < mydbfile.sql & then entered the password & got the

 error: ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 23: MySql server has gone away
```

when I tried to import the database file using phpmyadmin after taking 3-4hrs it also results in the errors

like: No data received

is there any other way like reading the .sql file using the php & inserting into the database one by one. is it good way?

any idea what could be the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know that phpmyadmin has it own upload file limit, but the mysql command should work. Maybe check the mysql max connection time?

Comment: @We0 I run this query : SHOW VARIABLES LIKE  'wait_timeout' & `interactive_timeout` & got 28800

Comment: For the error `No data received` try checking the path to the .sql file.
For importing large files, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file).

Comment: @Dinesh the .sql file path is currect,  already checked that

Answer (score 2):

I think you should split the .sql insert commands and import them in multiple phases. Do check the "max connection time" setting.

You can also try http://www.ozerov.de/bigdump/

Comment: the .slq file contains 7Lacks + records it will take lot of time, any other option?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because of `max_allowed_packet`

Change in the `my.ini/my.cnf` file. Include the single line under `[mysqld]` in your file

```
max_allowed_packet=500M
```

now `restart the MySQL service` once you are done.
You can see it's curent value in mysql like this:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet'
```

You can try to change it like this, but it's unlikely this will work on shared hosting:

```
SET GLOBAL max_allowed_packet=16777216;
```

You can read about it here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/packet-too-large.html

Comment: I run this query: SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet' & got the result 
`Variable_name Value`
`max_allowed_packet    16777216` already, I mean I set that already but the problem persists

Comment: Try to set it larger size say 500M. And try again. The size of the row to be inserted show be less than the max_allowed_packet

Comment: ok but I already set max_allowed_packet = 2G in my my.cnf file

Comment: Can you execute this SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet' and paste the result?

Comment: I am sorry satishD but I think you didn't noticed my first comment on your answer, anyways I got result as: 16777216

Comment: @sandip that is what my confusion was. 16777216=16M.... but you mentioned that it was changed to 2G where the result should be