# Importing 40GB+ .sql file

Tags: mysql

What is a way to import a 40GB+ `.sql` file into a MySQL database, that works?

I tried big dump. I tried loading the `.sql` into workbench and executing.

None of the methods I tried so far, have worked.

I was wondering what is the best way or even a-way (that works) of importing such a large database `.sql` into mysql? Note that splitting the SQL file into chunks may not work, as some tables are larger than 5GB.

I appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: start mysql console client `use` your database and insert `\. dump.sql`

Comment: try to import it with the mysql commandline tools

Comment: Use `mysql` cli, like `mysql -uUSER -p DATABASE < dump.sql > result.txt` (you'll be prompted to type password). It won't be extremely faster, but will do dump restore in background. File `result.txt` will contain any errors or other result messages

Comment: Both and I tried the method above and it starts out well but then I get a notification after some time, saying: `Error 2006 (HY000): MySQL Server has gone away`.

Comment: How was this dump file created? Is there any possibility to regenerate it in a different way, in particular splitting huge tables into individual INSERT statements?

Comment: try this for the import http://stackoverflow.com/a/12425526/1251601

Comment: @Mike dump file was created using a mysql dump from the command line

Comment: Increasing the package size is an obvious improvement, but if you have a single package of 5GB then you are doomed. I doubt you can set such a large value for the server.

Comment: Thanks everyone, this was all very helpful. I was able to resolve this issue by combining your suggestions, hints and clues with some additional research from other posts. Posted the solution I ended up using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Step 1:** Make changes to the configuration file: `my.cnf` (located in `C:\ProgramData` directory in Windows if running MySQL V5.6, **Note:** this directory is hidden by default, you must enable visibility of hidden files in Folder Options).

`max_allowed_packet=2000M`

**Step 2:** Restart MySQL service

**Step 3:** Use the following dump command:

```
mysql -hhostname -uusername -ppassword db_name
< C:\sql_input_path\db.sql > C:\error_log_output_path\error.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

I imported a big dump file like this: mysql -u username -p database_name < your_dump.sql

Comment: What's the difference from existing comments? Suppose this should be comment too.

Comment: i just posted the obvious way as an answer so he can accept it?!

Comment: +1, Thanks for the reply, this was a step in the right direction :)