# MySQL CSV Import Issue

Tags: php, mysql, csv, import, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to upload a CSV into a mysql database using phpmyadmin

When I try with a shortened version of the database, the process works ok, but when I try with the full database, I get the error:

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

The section of my CSV that is working is:

```
trans_id,price_paid,date,postcode,property_type,poperty_type_2,hold,add_num,add_flat,add_road,add_area,add_city,add_borough,add_county,add_rand
{33C588EE-BB09-4F6F-BA8C-000312C72B3B},159950,23/05/2014 00:00,SL6 9LX,F,N,L,2,,THE SHAW,COOKHAM,MAIDENHEAD,WINDSOR AND MAIDENHEAD,WINDSOR AND MAIDENHEAD,A
{2C650B8C-57C0-421C-A4A9-00037BDFDCFB},158000,30/05/2014 00:00,NN14 1RJ,T,N,F,4,,MIDLAND COTTAGES,RUSHTON,KETTERING,KETTERING,NORTHAMPTONSHIRE,A
{74FA45D0-CB64-40E1-94C4-00055AEBF72C},470000,30/05/2014 00:00,KT20 5SF,D,N,F,11,,CHAPEL ROAD,,TADWORTH,REIGATE AND BANSTEAD,SURREY,A
{054AB14B-0EED-48FD-B3CD-0005B154A5C3},135000,23/05/2014 00:00,NR27 9AZ,F,N,L,48,,ALBANY COURT,,CROMER,NORTH NORFOLK,NORFOLK,A
{86896E40-68BA-4BA2-8468-0006258B9C41},124995,09/05/2014 00:00,L24 9NA,S,Y,L,131,,ADDENBROOKE DRIVE,SPEKE,LIVERPOOL,LIVERPOOL,MERSEYSIDE,A
{A948BD6F-DD91-4DE9-82D1-0008226FC360},95000,13/06/2014 00:00,HU6 7XE,S,N,F,51,,DOWNFIELD AVENUE,,HULL,CITY OF KINGSTON UPON HULL,CITY OF KINGSTON UPON HULL,A
{7191F69F-7648-4603-9CE7-000882808E16},174000,19/05/2014 00:00,DT5 1HX,T,N,F,2,,LONG ACRE,,PORTLAND,WEYMOUTH AND PORTLAND,DORSET,A
{525BE511-1351-475F-9765-0009645D0B60},328000,11/06/2014 00:00,TW18 2EP,T,N,F,1,,EDGELL ROAD,,STAINES-UPON-THAMES,SPELTHORNE,SURREY,A
```

I've tried:

increasing the `max_packet=64M` in /etc/my.cnf to 64M, and the `wait_timeout= 1000` but no luck.

I've also made the same changes for the packet size limit on the php.ini but no luck.

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks,

Mo

Comment: Check their answers [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on [MySQL error #2006](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html).  I've included some of the more likely possibilities below:

- You have encountered a timeout on the server side and the automatic reconnection in the client is disabled (the reconnect flag in the MYSQL structure is equal to 0).
- You can also get these errors if you send a query to the server that is incorrect or too large. If mysqld receives a packet that is too large or out of order, it assumes that something has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. If you need big queries (for example, if you are working with big BLOB columns), you can increase the query limit by setting the server's max_allowed_packet variable, which has a default value of 1MB. You may also need to increase the maximum packet size on the client end. More information on setting the packet size is given in Section B.5.2.10, “Packet Too Large”.  *This likely isn't the issue, as you've already done the suggested solution.*
- You also get a lost connection if you are sending a packet 16MB or larger if your client is older than 4.0.8 and your server is 4.0.8 and above, or the other way around.

There's also an error specific for Windows applications, so if you're using Windows, check that out:

- You are using a Windows client and the server had dropped the connection (probably because wait_timeout expired) before the command was issued.  The problem on Windows is that in some cases MySQL does not get an error from the OS when writing to the TCP/IP connection to the server, but instead gets the error when trying to read the answer from the connection.  Prior to MySQL 5.0.19, even if the reconnect flag in the MYSQL structure is equal to 1, MySQL does not automatically reconnect and re-issue the query as it doesn't know if the server did get the original query or not.  The solution to this is to either do a mysql_ping() on the connection if there has been a long time since the last query (this is what Connector/ODBC does) or set wait_timeout on the mysqld server so high that it in practice never times out.