# MySQL import command only returns the help info

Tags: mysql, wamp

I want to import an .sql file into a database on my local WAMP environment on Win7 64bit. I used this command before already, and it worked then - now, it just seems to fail without an error. Instead, MySQL simply returns the help/usage file.

My import command: `mysql.exe -u root -p password database_name < db.sql`

MySQL returns:

> mysql.exe  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.1.53, for Win64 (unknown)
>   Copyright (c) 2000, 2010, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.
>   This software comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software,
>   and you are welcome to modify and redistribute it under the GPL v2 license
>   Usage: mysql.exe [OPTIONS] [database]

(followed by the long list of possible commands).

When I type a different command such as:
`mysql.exe use database_name`, the exact same thing happens. This leads me to believe there is something wrong with my setup.

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: what is the .sql file size? Try to increase the accepted filesize, timeout parameters in mysql.ini

Comment: The file is 360MB. I only have a my.ini; the `max_allowed_packet` was 16M. I just set it to 1024M, but I'm still getting the same error...

Comment: yes my.ini, related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file

Comment: MySQL didn't go away in this case - that's the issue. There are no kinds of errors, neither in the output nor in the log. Thanks for the reference, but unfortunately it doesn't seem to do anything here.

Comment: same difference, sometimes it goes away or just stops importing more, it is a case of my.ini configuration

Comment: unless your .sql has errors

Answer (score 0):

You are not supposed to enter the password on the command line, in ase someone is looking over your shoulder (security). You just enter the `-p` to make sql.exe prompt you for the passord.

So instead of this

My import command:

```
mysql.exe -u root -p password database_name < db.sql
```

Try this :

```
mysql.exe -u root -p database_name < db.sql
```

`mysql.exe` will then ask you for the password and then comeplete the requested actions.

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues had this error and he had an em dash `—` instead of a dash `-`. Replacing the em dash by the dash solved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem for my case is I put a semi-colon at the end of the command.
Remove it, problem gone.