# upload .sql 500 error

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

When i try upload .sql file i get **500 error**,

file size is **5mb**

I see when 500 error come go and cpu high and source is **apache2**

I change in php.ini from 8mb to 100mb but again same

I use ubuntu 14.04, Vestacp

Answer (score 0):

Possibly PHP timeout being reached, try adjusting `max_execution_time` and `max_input_time` in php.ini to higher values.

You might also want to try splitting up the sql file into chunks to see if it works.

Comment: where to edit max_execution_time  and max_input_time ? my.cnf ?

Comment: in php.ini, since you mentioned you could change another setting there previously.

Comment: the values are in seconds, so try making them 300 or something.

Comment: i add that but get now ''#2006 - MySQL server has gone away''

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file if it helps.

Comment: glad to know! you might want to add your own answer and accept it. or i could edit my answer to include it as well.