# MySQL server has gone away in wampserver

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, wampserver

I try to import a csv file into phpmyadmin using wampserver.

I created the db and I go to import option.

I select the file which is 26MB.

I select to keep the line as the name of values.

Finally I receive this:

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

How can I import the file?

Comment: Next to the file upload there should be "max upload". What does that say for you?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Server has gone away when importing large sql file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file)

Answer (score 0):

You can use command to import tables into database as below :

`mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -hHOSTNAME DATABASENAME < FILEPATH`

FilePath must be like : `/home/xxx/Desktop/abc.sql`
`