# MySql Gone away when import from large file

Tags: mysql

I have a 300MB `.sql` file and I Read [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file), Based On that I set `Max Allowed Packet` to 1024MB and TimeOut equal to 16000. Then I restarted mysql. Even After that I encounter with `MySql Gone away` Error When I import, Then just some of tables importing. I'm doing this on a CentOS server.
What Should I Do!?

Any help will be Appreciated.

Comment: Are you importing via phpMyAdmin like the question you referenced?  Also, what do you get if you run `SELECT @@max_allowed_packet, @@wait_timeout, @@net_read_timeout, @@net_write_timeout;` ?

Comment: @AC No! I use command line Mysql, `1048576`, `28800`, `30`, `60` respectively

Comment: Can you please include the command(s) that you use to import the file?  How about the results of `show variables like '%timeout%';` and `show global variables like '%timeout%';` -- I'm wondering if, for example, you're piping to the client in interactive mode, so your interactive_timeout is being used.  Your @@max_allowed_packet up there was 1MB, which is also a little fishy -- did you check [the various other possible config files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html)?

Comment: I'm totally confused. I'm using `mysql -u root -p t2 < /home/myfile.sql` to do that! @AC