# when i used to connect with phpmyadmin using netbeans in php programming language i got some error

Tags: php, html, mysql, phpmyadmin

This is my code for connecting to database:

```
$datbase=mysqli_connect("localhost:82","root"," ");
if(!$datbase)
{
    die("connection failed".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

it shows me that

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): MySQL server has gone away in C:\Program Files\apache24\Apache24\htdocs\PhpProject3\php_DataBase.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_connect(): Error while reading greeting packet. PID=10848 in C:\Program Files\apache24\Apache24\htdocs\PhpProject3\php_DataBase.php on line 9

Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2006): MySQL server has gone away in C:\Program Files\apache24\Apache24\htdocs\PhpProject3\php_DataBase.php on line 9
```

line number 9 is `database=mysqli_connect("localhost:82","root"," ")`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Server has gone away when importing large sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error in this line and also remove space in password

```
$datbase=mysqli_connect("localhost:82","root"," ");
```

You are not connecting to MySQL, but to Apache server. If you didn't change MySQL port just use

```
$datbase=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","databaseName");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should read first http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php.

```
$link = mysqli_connect("host", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
```

Try this:

```
$datbase=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","my_db");
if(!$datbase)
{
    die("connection failed".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this line with

```
 $datbase=mysqli_connect("localhost:82","root"," ");
```

with this one

```
   $datbase=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","your database name");
```

Answer (score 0):

you are using port number on localhost that you are not set in `php.ini` file

try like this

```
//$datbase=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","databaseName");

$datbase=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","databaseName");
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `Mysql` server is runs with `default settings` means . you don't need specify the port number . otherwise you need to specify `port number` as `5th` parameter . like below Example .

Mysql default port number is `3306`

```
$datbase=mysqli_connect("localhost","username","password","database_name","port_number");
if(!$datbase)
{
     die("connection failed".mysqli_connect_error());
}
```