# MySQL gone away error running mysql command large file

Tags: mysql, ssh

I want to load a large .sql file (1.5GB) but everytime it stuck on 623.9 MB with the error: MySQL server has gone away.

Running the following command: `mysql -u {DB-USER-NAME} -p {DB-NAME} < {db.file.sql path}`

Already changed my my.cnf file with the following values, but that did not help:

```
wait_timeout = 3600
max_allowed_packet = 100M
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 2000
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: 1) Did you restart the server after changes? (just a reminder).
2) Try make those values even bigger. Longer timeouts, larger packet size.
3) Try break up large queries: INSERT INTO table VALUES (a),(b),...(z) => INSERT INTO table VALUES (a),(b),...(m); INSERT INTO table VALUES (n),(o),...(z);

Comment: How long does it takes to receive this error?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this link  - 
[MySQL Server has gone away when importing large sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file)  - 
for various combinations that have worked for this problem.