# MySQL server has gone away on geoname allcountriess

Tags: php, mysql

[image]

i'm tring to add geoname allcountries in my database
after adding some data show  MySQL server has gone away

allmost after  37890 rows then show show MySQL server has gone

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `geo_allcountries`;

CREATE TABLE `geo_allcountries` (
    `geonameid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `asciiname` VARCHAR(200) DEFAULT NULL,
    `alternatenames` VARCHAR(4000) DEFAULT NULL,
    `latitude` DECIMAL(10 , 7 ) DEFAULT NULL,
    `longitude` DECIMAL(10 , 7 ) DEFAULT NULL,
    `fclass` CHAR(1) DEFAULT NULL,
    `fcode` VARCHAR(10) DEFAULT NULL,
    `country` VARCHAR(2) DEFAULT NULL,
    `cc2` VARCHAR(60) DEFAULT NULL,
    `admin1` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `admin2` VARCHAR(80) DEFAULT NULL,
    `admin3` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `admin4` VARCHAR(20) DEFAULT NULL,
    `population` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `elevation` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `gtopo30` INT(11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `timezone` VARCHAR(40) DEFAULT NULL,
    `moddate` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`geonameid`),
    KEY `name` (`name`),
    KEY `asciiname` (`asciiname`),
    KEY `latitude` (`latitude`),
    KEY `longitude` (`longitude`),
    KEY `fclass` (`fclass`),
    KEY `fcode` (`fcode`),
    KEY `country` (`country`),
    KEY `cc2` (`cc2`),
    KEY `admin1` (`admin1`),
    KEY `population` (`population`),
    KEY `elevation` (`elevation`),
    KEY `timezone` (`timezone`)
) ENGINE=MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=UTF8 COLLATE UTF8_UNICODE_CI;



ALTER TABLE `geo_allcountries` DISABLE KEYS;


LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/allCountries.txt'
INTO TABLE `geo_allcountries`
CHARACTER SET 'UTF8';



ALTER TABLE `geo_allcountries` 
ADD COLUMN `fclasscode` CHAR(7) CHARACTER SET 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci' NULL DEFAULT NULL AFTER `fcode`;

UPDATE `geo_allcountries` 
SET 
    `fclasscode` = CONCAT(`fclass`, '.', `fcode`);

UPDATE `geo_allcountries` 
SET  `fclasscode` = ''
WHERE
    `fclasscode` NOT REGEXP '[A-Z]{1}.[A-Z]{1,5}';

ALTER TABLE `geo_allcountries` ADD INDEX `fclasscode` (`fclasscode` ASC);


ALTER TABLE `geo_allcountries` ENABLE KEYS;
```

add this line have the same error
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;

php config

```
max_allowed_packet = 2048M

$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] =0;
```

with this   same error

```
$cfg['ExecTimeLimit'] =3000;



post_max_size=1800M
upload_max_filesize=2048M
max_execution_time=2048
max_input_time=1700M
memory_limit=1048M
```

file size of geoname allcountries.txt file is 1.38GB

how to solve this and where is a problem

I spend much time on this issue but i'm unable to slove

please find out and how to solve this

Comment: ON needs to be quoted, or use 1 instead.

Comment: like as  SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 'ON';

Comment: That is correct, or `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;`

Comment: show same error MySQL server has gone away

Comment: SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS =1; still error

Comment: Server has gone away tends to be a MySQL configuration issue, which some needs to be tweaked in the my.cnf. That large a file can take awhile.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Server has gone away when importing large sql file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12425287/mysql-server-has-gone-away-when-importing-large-sql-file)