# MySQL server has gone away on UPDATE (Huge QUERY, around 85MB) using mysli PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question has been posted / asked *many* times, and many answers have been given.
However, to my knowledge, none of them seems to work for now.

So here is the problem:
When updating on a HUGE query , ~85 MB for single UPDATE query  (please spare me the 'you should reconsider your database design' , not by choice) , PHP gives me the following error : 
**MySQL server has gone away.**

Now, this connection is local (~5 seconds to transfer 85MB)
(Most of the query update a LONGTEXT field)

Here is my setup :

1 Docker instance running APACHE + PHP 7
1 Docker instance running mysql 5.7

my.cnf

```
[mysqld]
datadir=/var/lib/mysql
socket=/mysql.sock
user=root
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
ft_min_word_len=1
max_allowed_packet=1G

innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
innodb_log_file_size=512M
max_connections=10000
query_cache_size=128M
skip_name_resolve
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
sql_mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"

interactive_timeout = 9999
wait_timeout = 9999
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 9999
net_read_timeout = 9999
net_write_timeout = 9999
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
connect_timeout = 1000000
net_buffer_length = 256M

[mysqld_safe]
log-error=/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
innodb_file_per_table=1
ft_min_word_len=1
max_allowed_packet=1G

innodb_buffer_pool_size=1024M
innodb_log_file_size=512M
max_connections=10000
query_cache_size=128M
skip_name_resolve
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

interactive_timeout = 9999
wait_timeout = 9999
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 9999
net_read_timeout = 9999
net_write_timeout = 9999
explicit_defaults_for_timestamp = TRUE
connect_timeout = 1000000
net_buffer_length = 256M


[mysqldump]
max_allowed_packet = 1G
```

(I'm aware MySQL is running as root & this is bad practice)

I also tried with & without

```
mysqli.reconnect = On
```

in my php.ini , but didnt work.

Is there any options i am not aware of ?

Thanks again for your time on a such common problem.

Comment: what's the actual query?

Comment: UPDATE `invoices` SET `serialized_infos` = '[85 MB of base64]' WHERE `idx`= 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it ! The culprit was the mysql compression : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Removed the compression and everything works ! :)
-- This answer should be known to everyone to avoid multiple hours of pure headaches ---

Comment: In that particular case, No it wasnt. It's in a comment below the actual manual. It really is a bug from MySQL.

Comment: In my case it _was_ compression, enabled through `mysqli_real_connect(..., MYSQLI_CLIENT_COMPRESS)`, effectively limiting any query size to 16M, even with `max_allowed_packet` set to 1G. If I could I would give 100 upvotes, as I just lost 3 hours while debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have too short timeout for sockets.
Edit php.ini or cheat with ini_set.
Might be too low values in mysql for query size too.

To insert a large mysql query you must tweak both mysql and php

PHP:

1. memory_limit
2. max_execution_time

MySQL:

Verify settings so they are large enough:

1. max_allowed_packet
2. wait_timeout
3. For innodb: innodb_log_file_size

Comment: Mysql : | wait_timeout                                      | 9999
| max_allowed_packet       | 1073741824 |
| slave_max_allowed_packet | 1073741824 |

Comment: Ok that's over 1 Gb which is fine. Could you check `wait_timeout` as well?

Comment: Small queries works well? (just checking so it isn't connect_timeout that fails).

Comment: Yes they do :) In fact, the big query is done when compiling a sales report : many other queries before the big one works just fine

Comment: Ok, then it's not a tcp timeout either.

Comment: hmm you should be able to print the error code from mysql. It throws an exception in PHP I guess?

Comment: It doesnt give a php error : I had to print it myself using mysql_error(), and it just says : MySQL server has gone away

Comment: echo `echo mysqli_errno($link);` and `echo mysqli_error($link);`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165595/discussion-between-niclas-larsson-and-charles-ugo-brouillard).