# Command line options to mysql server (running as a service)

Tags: mysql

I've got a local mysql server running on my system, which I'm trying to load a massive existing database into from an sqldump file.

The first time I tried this after about an hour (or so) I got the following error

```
'ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL...
```

It seems I might be able to sort this out be rectified by increasing the `--wait_timeout` [command line option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query).

**My question is - how can you start mysql server as a service and pass it command line options in Ubuntu?**

To start and stop normally I use

```
sudo service mysql [start|stop]
```

but passing arguments here doesn't work. Alternativly, if I start it as a daemon process

```
sudo mysqld --wait_timeout <#>
```

How do I then shut it down in a safe way (I'd imagine 'CTRL-C' or `kill -9'ing it would be bad).

System info (if relevant):

```
mysqld  Ver 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))
Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of putting that option on the command line, you may put the option in `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`. Just make sure the option is in the section `[mysqld]`. Please refer to https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_wait_timeout for the name to be used in option file.

Another way to change the option maybe change the option on a running MySQL server, by executing this SQL:

```
SET GLOBAL wait_timeout = <value>;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try increasing max_allowed_packet to something quite large like 32M.  I've never understood this well, but I think it could solve your issue.