# How can I execute SQL queries that take longer 99,999 seconds on MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql-workbench

UPDATE: the issue is now [fixed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33490832/395857).

---

I would like to execute a query that takes more than 99,999 seconds to execute (e.g. `SELECT SLEEP(150000);`). To change the timeout in MySQL Workbench, we have to go to *Edit → Preferences → SQL Editor → DBMS connection read time out (in seconds)*. However, the `DBMS connection read time out` field only accept up to 5 figures, and setting the field to 0 is equivalent to the default parameter (600 seconds). If the query takes more time than the timeout, I get the error message: `Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Hence my question: is it possible to increase this limit to over 99,999 seconds? 
I use Windows 7 64-bit Ultimate with MySQL Workbench 5.2.47 CE.

The `DBMS connection read time out` field:
[image]

Timeout issue (0 is equivalent to the default parameter (600 seconds)):
[image]

Comment: No. And seriously? You need to manually run a query that takes more than 27 hours? Maybe you should re-assess the situation...

Comment: You really shouldn't run queries in production that take more than a few minutes or so. If there's a lot of data, run it in small batches.

Comment: Thanks! I need to extract some information from a 50 GB table and put them into a new table. During this extraction I do some in-memory joins to replace some text attributes by corresponding ID (foreign keys). I don't understand yet why this query takes more than 99,999 seconds, but while I investigate it running some `EXPLAIN` I was curious to know if there is any way to circumvent this 99,999-second limit in MySQL Workbench. Usually setting to the parameter 0 means infinite: is there any technical issue explaining why MySQL Workbench doesn't allow that?

Comment: I think I can see how to optimize your `SELECT SLEEP(150000)` statement.

Comment: @chiastic-security :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably nobody ever thought you'd need such a high timeout, so you are limited to what is settable currently. But open a feature request on http://bugs.mysql.com to suggest either having 0 disable the timeout entirely or allow bigger values.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in Europe we consider the comma a decimal-separator. Did you actually mean 100k of seconds? I see in your comments that you are handling 50 GB. Even so, if you need longer than an hour, you missed the Indeces. You must know that they won´t get properly rebuildt in a single query, so if you join on a massive insert, You get the cartesian product of rows scanned - in other words, your query could happen to run for weeks or even months.

Solution:

1. Fill in basic data, use no joins here.
2. Alter table to set index.
3. Run `ANALYZE <tablename>`
4. Do everything else.

If you feel that you have trouble following that procedure, prepend your Query with the `EXPLAIN` keyword and post the results.

(I have a cronjob importing about 80GB every 30 minutes in place - MySQL surely can handle this.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, yep I meant 100k seconds. Using indices indeed allowed to reduce the runtime to 1 hour only for the particular query that initiated this question, but I'm still curious to know in MySQL Workbench how I could execute a query takes more than 99,999 seconds :) I don't see the point in putting such a limit.

Answer (score 1):

This issue is now solved in MySQL Workbench 6.0.3 (2013-07-09): See the [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=69395) and the [change log](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/workbench-relnotes-en/wb-news-6-0-3.html).