# MySQL long query: Lost connection to MYSQL server during query

Tags: mysql

I have a query that is about 10000 characters long and it fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

This only happens when a local client (either PHP or CLI) connects to a remote database server.

If I try to do this same query from another (windows) maxhine, it works perfectly on the same database server. So the server settings are not the problem.

I have tried adding `--max_allowed_packet=16M` to my mysql client startup, but still the error occures.

Further testing reveals that the max query length that can be executed is limited at around 5000 characters.

Some version info:

```
mysql -V
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.32, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.2
```

Any idea what I could try?

Comment: Post the mysql error.log contents.

Comment: Server error log is empty. One more indication it is a client error.

Answer (score 0):

The error 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query' usually occurs due to some trouble in network connectivity. 
Possible causes and solution are -

1. Please try to increase net_read_timeout.
2. Check onnect_timeout - Default is 10 sec , increase it to larger value.
3. Increase max_allowed_packet.

More details are mentioned here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/error-lost-connection.html

[Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)