# Error 2013 in MySQL export database

Tags: mysql, database

my MySQL server was working fine, but today I can't connect to this. I get the error "Can't connect to mysql server on 'localhost' (10061)". So I check that the Mysql55 service in my Windows 7 x64 is stopped. I start the service, but when I open a specifically database the server stops. With other databases I don't have any problem.

I try to dump the database to a .sql file and I get the error "mysqldump: Error 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query when dumping table `table_name` at row: 43795". Then the server stops. I try this [Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query) but not works.

When I try to export the database in other times, I get the same error, but with a different row value.

Answer (score 0):

It seems while dumping the particular table sending receiving too large data from that table .

use --max_allowed_packet=500M and then dump it..also check your my.ini config file max_allowed_packet variable size you have specified .