# Mysql Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query 44.515 sec

Tags: mysql-workbench, mysql-error-2013

I have a table called products2 with about 830,000 rows in it. When I had about 500,000 rows, the query runs slow but fine. And now when I try to query something, it almost doesnt return anything in Mysql Workbench. Showing the following error:

```
>**strong text**Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  44.515 sec
```

I thought it has something to do with my Workbench connection to my database on Go-daddy host, but same thing happens even if I go straight to PHPadmin online tool. I have Product ID as primary key, unique index, not null and auto increment. The full table structure below:

- ProductID int(11) AI PK
- SupplierPartNum varchar(100)
- OemPartNum varchar(100)
- UPC varchar(45)
- CostPrice decimal(10,2)
- CompatibleWith text
- ProductName varchar(500)
- Brand varchar(45)
- Manufacturer varchar(45)
- Supplier int(11)
- Category varchar(45)
- SubCategory varchar(100)
- Notes text
- Notes2 varchar(500)
- Quantity int(11)
- PageYield varchar(45)
- Condition varchar(45)
- Color varchar(45)
- Description varchar(21844)
- IsTruckShip varchar(45)
- UnitOfMeasure varchar(45)
- MinQty int(11)
- Width decimal(8,2)
- Length decimal(8,2)
- Height decimal(8,2)
- Weight decimal(8,2)
- Returnable varchar(5)
- Warranty varchar(100)
- SubCategory2 varchar(100)
- ImageUrl1 varchar(150)

Queries failed (pretty much any query now fails):

> select * from Products2 where Supplier = 15 and Description is not null and ImageUrl1 is not null 
>            and flag2 = 1;
>
> select *from Products2 where Supplier = 10;

Did some research and increase the timeout. But doesn't help. I worked with Microsoft Sql before in Management studio and dealed with millions of rows before in mssql, it was fast and easy. I just dont get why doesn't it work in mysql, I am a newbie. I dont think this problem can be solve if my database is on localhost. The internet should be fast enough.

The server is sitting at godaddy's server as I have a hosting plan with them. I dont see any options on their website to set any configuration for the server.

Please help me. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Comment: I've looked at that post before and tried to set the Mysql session by setting: > Edit → Preferences → SQL Editor → DBMS connection read time out (in seconds): 6000. I am using Godaddy's hosting and all my database is there. I can't find how to set the max_allowed_packet and idk where to locate that my.ini file. Is it because the server is on Godaddy, hence I dont have any flexibility? I am new to mysql. Please help. Thanks.

Comment: If you are on windows your my.ini will be located in the default path (assuming you did not change where your data is stored) C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6 , the file will be called `my`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29086366/lost-connection-to-mysql-during-query-mysql-workbench/29087889?noredirect=1#comment46409606_29087889