# mysql workbench "Lost connection to mysql server"

Tags: mysql, timeout, group-concat

First I need to indicate that I ran the sql file for the Wikipedia dump on my machine, and to be able to run that I needed to update many settings regarding the index size available on memory and some other settings. I just want to mention that those large sql queries were run successfully and I didn't have any problem regarding memory or time out.

Now I have a table pagelinks (pl_from, pl_title) that shows the links that appears in each wikipedia page, for example the data can be (1, "title1"), (1,"title2"), (2, "title3"), (2, "title1"). I want to create a table that concat the titles group by pl_from. For that this is my sql query (I am using workbench):

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len=150000;
create table concatpagelinks 
(SELECT pl_from, GROUP_CONCAT(pl_title , ' ') as links FROM pagelinks GROUP BY pl_from)
```

Running this query I got the error : "Lost connection to mysql server during query" and the system asked me again for the password. So I search and found [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/error-lost-connection.html). Therefore I changed net_read_timeout to 1000 and connect_timeout to 60. It didn't solve the problem, SO I changed the query to :

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len=150000;
create table concatpagelinks 
(SELECT pl_from, GROUP_CONCAT(pl_title , ' ') as links FROM pagelinks GROUP BY pl_from limit 0,1000)
```

Still the same problem, and the amazing thing is that every time the query is run for 600.495 sec and the error happens.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can try to change the timeout value on Workbench. 
Go to:  Edit → Preferences → SQL Editor → DBMS connection read time out

See this post for more details:

[Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query/12790569#12790569)

Or try to increase the value in:
Edit → Preferences → SQL Editor → DBMS_Connection keep alive interval

Comment: I tried this one and it seems working because I didn't get any error in 10 minutes. Thank you.

Comment: Dont forget to restart MySQL Workbench after you changed the settings...

Comment: Increase or _decrease_ the `DBMS connection keep-alive interval`? It should be _decrease_, no?