# Lost connection on DELETE FROM, not on SELECT

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb, mysql-error-2006, mysql-error-2013

I am attempting to the record of a specific Member if it no longer has child records in another table.  When I commit the DELETE FROM, I am receiving a Lost Connection or MySQL server has gone away.  If I SELECT the same record from the database, I get a valid return. I have included the interaction below:

```
SELECT m.* FROM Member m LEFT OUTER JOIN MemberAssociation ma ON m.memberID = ma.memberID WHERE m.scanCode = 12345 AND ma.associationCode IS NULL;
/* The expected Member records, which appear to be valid.  2 Rows */

DELETE m.* FROM Member m LEFT OUTER JOIN MemberAssociation ma ON m.memberID = ma.memberID WHERE m.scanCode = 12345 AND ma.associationCode IS NULL;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query

DELETE m.* FROM Member m LEFT OUTER JOIN MemberAssociation ma ON m.memberID = ma.memberID WHERE m.scanCode = 12345 AND ma.associationCode IS NULL;
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
Connection id:    2
Current database: my_database

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

Is it possible that there is something I can do to fix this problem, or is it more likely that I stumbled across a software bug?

I am running innodb_version: 5.6.19-67.0 and MariaDB version: 10.0.13-MariaDB.  The Member table is an InnoDB table.

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE for the two tables.

Comment: Try this query: `DELETE FROM Member m 
WHERE m.scanCode = 12345
and m.memberID IN(
select ma.memberID MemberAssociation ma
where ma.associationCode IS NULL
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue myself and have some recommendations about anyone experiencing something like this in the future.

In my case, MySQL was failing because of a table corruption.  I found the error by using the `CHECK TABLE` tool.

```
CHECK TABLE Member;
+-------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| Table                   | Op    | Msg_type | Msg_text |
+-------------------------+-------+----------+----------+
| my_database.Member | check | status   | OK       |
+-------------------------+-------+----------+----------+

CHECK TABLE MemberAssociation;
ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

I then tried to copy the data out, but could not due to a `PRIMARY KEY` issue:

```
CREATE TABLE MemberAssociation_recover LIKE MemberAssociation

INSERT INTO MemberAssociation_recover SELECT * FROM MemberAssociation;
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'XXXXX-YYYYY-ZZZZ' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Something is wrong obviously.

At this point I did a `mysqldump` and discovered that there was a duplicate for the majority of rows in the `MemberAssociation` table.  Because this was a development database, I restored the data via the following procedure:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE MemberAssociationIgnore LIKE MemberAssociation;
INSERT IGNORE INTO MemberAssociationIgnore SELECT * FROM MemberAssociation;
DELETE FROM MemberAssociation;
INSERT INTO MemberAssociation SELECT * FROM MemberAssociationIgnore;
```

Note: On a production system, I would not follow the above procedure.  I would recommend copying the data out of the corrupted table into a new table that has no keys and manually cleaning out any duplicates before applying the removed keys and then copying the data back into the original table.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the [MySQL:MariaDB](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html) for a background on when this happens.

A [related SO query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query) also discusses on the same issue.

Basically, it appears that your DELETE query may be taking too long and the MySQL server-client connection times out.

**EDIT Based on response from OP**

As per [this](https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/mysql-and-percona-server/11217-corrupted-innodb-table-crashing-mysql-instance-how-to-recover-table) link a corrupted Innodb table can also cause this problem. Refer to the below 2 links for the diagnostic and troubleshooting process:

- [Recovering from a corrupted InnoDB index](https://www.percona.com/forums/questions-discussions/mysql-and-percona-server/11217-corrupted-innodb-table-crashing-mysql-instance-how-to-recover-table)
- [Fixing Innodb table    corruption](http://contrarianwisdom.blogspot.in/2009/06/fixing-innodb-table-corruption-mysql.html)

Comment: I have referenced the SO post you linked, but do not feel that it is applicable here.  I have a net_read_timeout of 30, wait_timeout of 28800 and interactive_timeout of 28800.  Furthermore, the query reports the Lost Connection immediately after I try to run it.  These timeouts are said to happen in seconds, the error returns in less than a second.