# Unable to Create a Table in MySQL Database (Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query)

Tags: mysql

I am unable to create a Table in one of the databases in MySQL. In the same MySQL Server, I can create a table in other databases. I am getting an error code as below.

**Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query**

Can someone please help at the earliest.

Answer (score 0):

This is what I found on quick google search

[Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/error-lost-connection.html

Comment: Yeah. I had tried it earlier. I changed net_read_timeout from 30 to 60. But still, the same error comes. My question is if I am able to query the existing tables of that database, why am I not able to run a create statement.