# Mysql lost connection during query

Tags: mysql, left-join

I created a view table, which combine two very large query (with multiples join tables) records is about few hundred thousand to million, when I try to run view table, after few minutes mysql return me "mysql lost connection during query", is anyone know how to fix this problem, due to i need to call the view table from excel.

Appreciate that if you could advice me on that.

Thank you

Comment: I don't know how to fix this, but relying on Excel to fix a database connection problem seems the wrong suggestion to me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen do you have any recommend for big data export to excel?

Comment: @Matt I tried that before, but it seem like not working for me.

Comment: Is there any chance of dumping the view to the machine where MySQL is actually running, and then transferring the CSV file to your machine which has Excel?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen but after export to csv, the data format will be corrupted.

Comment: No...you're asking for too many things at once.  This question is too broad.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen my question is how to fix solve it, when i receive "mysql connection lost during query", is there anywhere can avoid this happen.

Comment: I don't know your network settings.  Just the other day at work, I experienced an error similar to this.  My workaround was to avoid using a particular network drive which is known to be slow.