# Amazon Aurora MySQL: Lost connection to MySQL server during query

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-ec2, pymysql, amazon-aurora

I am using `pymysql` to query remote Amazon Aurora Db server from my EC2 instances. I am having issue that after a while I start getting exception:

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

The same script when I run locally on my Macbook on a local MySQL then issue does not happen.

How do I sort it out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Comment: @vahdet I have seen that question and this is why I specifically mentioned Aurora for AMazon. I should update tags though.

Comment: Is there a solution for this error?