# Lost connection to MySQL v8 server during query "Error Code: 2013."

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-error-2013

I need your help. When i run the query as noted below, Im getting the MySQL "error 2013: Lost connection". Im using a server v8.

```
SELECT CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(tblpatients.Lname,1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(tblpatients.Lname,2))) as lname, CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(tblpatients.mi,1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(tblpatients.mi,2))) as mi, 
CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(tblpatients.fname,1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(tblpatients.fname,2))) as fname, tblpatients.PhoneNum as PhoneNum, 
DATE_FORMAT(tblpatients.Bday,'%m/%d/%Y')as Bday, TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, Bday,CURDATE()) AS pxage, 
tblpatients.PatientID as PatientID, DATE_FORMAT(tblobgyne.obgyneDate,'%m/%d/%Y') as obgyneDate, TIME_FORMAT(tblobgyne.obgyneTime, '%h:%i%p') as obgyneTime, 
tblparity.ParityID, tblobgyne.OBGyneID, tblobgyne.chiefcomplain, tblobgyne.companyname as companyname, 
CONCAT(UCASE(LEFT(tblparity.pxservice,1)), LCASE(SUBSTRING(tblparity.pxservice,2))) as pxservice

FROM tblpatients
JOIN tblparity ON tblpatients.PatientID = tblparity.PatientID
JOIN tblobgyne ON tblparity.ParityID = tblobgyne.ParityID                                               
WHERE obgyneDate >= 03-20-2019 ORDER BY obgyneTime ASC;
```

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: `03-20-2019` isn't a date - `'2019-03-20'` is something mysql will recognise as a date. If you run `EXPLAIN {query}` and show the output  we could see if the tables are correctly indexed for this query.

Comment: @danblack Hey, thanks alot! i use this instead DATE_FORMAT(tblobgyne.obgyneDate,'%Y/%m/%d') >= '2019-03-20'

Comment: Don't use DATE_FORMAT on a date to convert it to a string and then rely on implicit conversion to get it back to a date. Madness (because it prevents index use). `WHERE obgyneDate >= '2019-03-20' ` is perfect.