# MySQL Lost connection on `check table`

Tags: mysql, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm using MySQL 5.7 on aws rds engine 5.7.mysql_aurora.2.04.3. I keep running into 
`ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query`.
It even happens when I run `check table foobars`.

The foobars table is InnoDB with over 15 million records and over 5 GB in size. I've set pretty much all of the timeout settings up really high but the issue still occurs. I'm using a db.r4.2xlarge instance.

Any ideas as to why this might be happening with 
`check table`? Additionally I also get the lost connection error when I do a `alter table` query.

Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Comment: Verify that the server isn't crashing and restarting -- that is one possible cause of this error and can happen due to a corrupted table or server-side bug.  `SHOW STATUS LIKE 'UPTIME';` shows seconds since server restart.  Run that before and after, and see if the number gets smaller (crash/restart) or larger (not).

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I have confirmed that the server isn't crashing and restarting. Uptime continues to get larger.

Answer (score 0):

I think part of the issue may have been that the long output of the `check table` query was crashing my client. I was able to get `check table` working by passing in the `--quick` flag when I connected with my mysql client.