# Connection Error Code: 2013 happening only for one specific table in MySQL Workbench, but all other tables work fine

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm using MySQL WorkBench 8.0 on Windows 10.

When I run a simple SELECT query

```
SELECT * FROM some_table;
```

It will eventually time out with the error

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

This only happens for one specific table, all other tables work just fine. I've tried setting the time out to longer than the default (30 seconds), but even after very long amounts of time it will still have the same result.

This is different from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query) because the OP was getting the error when adding an index to a table, but in my situation it happens for any query for only one table.

Comment: Could be one of 1) Time taken for query 2) Amount of data it tries to return 3) Possible corruption 4) Possible weird data in the table that the tool crashes on.

Comment: What happens if you issue the select statement from the mysql command line client instead of workbench?

Comment: try with a `limit` clause and check whether it occurs `SELECT * FROM some_table limit 10;`

Comment: Hey everyone, so I checked back this morning and the issue resolved itself.. I've asked my coworkers and no one touched the DB. So I don't know what the issue was, but here's my "solution"...btw the table was empty so I don't think it was too much data or anything