# Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query when running MySQL query

Tags: mysql

I had a bad table which I can't do anything on it and keeps return error with message:

```
Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
```

whenever I try to run any query that involve the bad table. I have tried to drop/repair the bad table but not working at all. It just keeps return the same error message.
 Anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: possible duplicate of 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query)

Comment: Solution was found, thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SHOW PROCESSLIST;
KILL <process_id>;
```

End up I found out that my query is stuck in process, I just list the process list and kill the stuck query process and the table is working fine now.