# Optimize MYSQL Select query in large table

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

Given the table:

```
CREATE TABLE `sample` (
    `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `vendorid` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
    `year` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `title` TEXT NOT NULL,
    `description` TEXT NOT NULL
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE
)
```

Table size: **over 7 million**. *All fields are **not unique**, except id.*

Simple query:

```
SELECT * FROM sample WHERE title='milk'
```

Takes over 45s-60s to complete.

Tried to put unique index on title and description but got 1170 error.

How could I optimize it? Would be very grateful for suggestions.

Comment: Just a `SELECT * FROM sample` will take 45s-60s, so I do not see the problem...

Comment: I hope there must be some sort of optimization. Because in my case, its unacceptable...

Comment: @TadasV. can you try `create index on sample(title(255));` and then run 2 versions of your query? `select ... where title = 'milk'` and `select ... where title like 'milk%'` and see if they are any faster?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`TEXT` columns need [prefix indexes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/column-indexes.html#column-indexes-prefix) -- it's not possible to index their entire contents; they can be too large. And, if the column values aren't unique, don't use UNIQUE indexes; they won't work.

Try this:

```sql
ALTER TABLE simple ADD INDEX title_prefix (title(64));
```

**Pro tip** For columns you need to use in WHERE statements, do your best to use `VARCHAR(n)`  where `n` is less than 768. Avoid `TEXT` and other [blob types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/blob.html) unless you absolutely need them; they can make for inefficient operation of your database server.

Comment: Thank you for advice! Performance with VAR improved to 5-20s!

Comment: Also the error resolved by https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: Note the 768 limit on index size is different in modern versions of MySQL. The limit is now 3072 bytes (reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-limits.html). Also keep in mind it's in _bytes_, not _characters_. The default character set is now utf8mb4, supporting up to 4 bytes per character.

Comment: @BillKarwin That's right. i mentioned the number 768 because it is 3072 / 4. That's the longest VARCHAR() indexable without a prefix when the charset is utf8mb4.