# Getting timeout after 300 seconds in MySql with workbench 8.0

Tags: mysql, timeout, mysql-workbench, workbench

When ever I run the query from MySql Workbench 8.0 getting an error after 300 seconds of execution.

`Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

we have below timeout settings from the server side.

[image]

And from the MySQL workbench side set the property
"DBMS connection read timeout interval (in seconds) set to 0"
**Under MenuBar ->  Edit -> Preferences -> SQL Editor**

Still getting the timeout issue. But when we run the same query by logging into the host machine not getting the timeout error.

Is there any property that I Need to change from MYSQL Workbench side ?

Comment: Have you tried the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query) ?

Comment: @ErgestBasha Tried already as mentioned . didn't worked