# MySQL Create a user that can only access a specific database, why can't I connect remotely?

Tags: mysql, database

I have remote access to `root` user.

The statement to create the user is as follows:

```sql
CREATE USER 'auser'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'auser';
GRANT ALL ON `MyDB`.* TO 'auser'@'%';
flush privileges;
```

This `auser` account cannot log in remotely, what is the reason?

PS. Use navicat to log in to the database prompt: `2013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`

Comment: `This auser account cannot log in remotely` if the user would have trouble log in the error should be something like Permission denied not `013 - Lost connection to MySQL server during query`.  As per the current error check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: @Ergest Basha The OP actually has a problem at login , not afterwards. And since his remote root access has no issue, I wonder if something else other than network problem is to blame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I login the user on Linux, mysql prompt `init_connect command failed` after execute `USE DatabaseName` .

I found the answer online. Change `/etc/my.cnf` from

```
init_connect=‘SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci’
init_connect=‘SET NAMES utf8’
```

to

```
init_connect='SET collation_connection = utf8_unicode_ci'
init_connect='SET NAMES utf8'
```

**Note the single quotes.**

Then restart mysql, the problem is solved.