# Lost connection for MYSQL while manipulating a certain row

Tags: mysql, database, transactions, foreign-keys, uuid

I have one table in Mysql named parent having id as primary key,

another table named child having a parent_id as foreign key which is linked to the id of the parent table,

I am trying to update an entry in the parent table for a specific id but I am getting the error "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query", otherwise it is working smoothly for all other ids.
I am also trying to insert an entry in the child table, everything works smoothly otherwise, except for one entry, that child entry's parent id already exists in the parent table as id, there is no foreign key error, just "Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query". I am not able to debug this because it is specific for only that id.

I have tried it multiple times through my code and also directly on Mysql workbench but did not reach any conclusion.

Comment: Can have a look on this solution : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: It is a very simple and small query, it hardly takes any miliseconds to execute... it is giving error only for a specific id... while it is working properly for any other id