MySQL performance issue while executing Views : Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query
I'm experiencing a significant performance issue with MySQL while executing queries on top of referencing my views and while executing that view which contains query of tables it is executing fine

It is generating the following error ----->
LIMIT 0, 1000 Error Code: 2013. Lost connection to MySQL server during query  30.016 sec
Here's the output of only executing the view for context :-) 
I tried to changed DBMS connection keep-alive interval (in seconds) ----->  6000
               DBMS connection read timeout interval (in seconds)---->  6000

               DBMS connection timeout interval (in seconds) -------->  6000

even after changing these connection time still cant get output

there are timeout options in settings page of workbench increase the tiimeout that you need

Does this help  -- > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10563619/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query?rq=2

what do you mean "on top of referencing my views"?   I'm not seeing a difference between the two screenshots?  is your end goal to run whatever query you are having problems with in workbench?  or are you just trying it out using workbench and you are having trouble with a query in an application?
