# Mysql server has gone away - MySQL error 2006:

Tags: php, mysql, database, windows-server-2003

When trying to edit table data in one of databases, I can't apply the change because of the error

> "MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away"`

This problem is intermittent. So I did some research on this and I came across this [post](http://Stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away). (note: I'm not at all knowledgeable on databases and php). Now I see mysql_ping Pings a server connection or reconnects it if there is no connection.

Sounds great. My issue is how do I apply this mysql_ping?  Where do I go and do it?  Is it ok to apply it or will it effect certain things?

My server runs off Windows 2003, IIS and I have PHP 5.3.8. I've had a look [here](https://www.php.net/mysql-ping) but I'm battling to understand it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Answer (score 0):

Make a subroutine/function that includes `mysql_ping`, and use it insted of `mysql_query`.

For example

```
<?php
function my_query($sql)
{
   if(!mysql_ping())
   {
      if(!mysql_connect( /* add connection parameters here */ ))
      {
         trigger_error("Database not avaible: " . mysql_error());
         return FALSE;
      }
   }

   return mysql_query($sql);
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but I wouldn't know where to add this function? MySQL administrator?

Comment: i always have all database stuff in one file, that the other files includes, there would be a good place to put it, and then replace all use of mysql_query( whit my_query(

Comment: Been a layman of PHP, I'd appreciate if you could elaborate? Where are those file that you are talking about?