# How to resolve error "#2006 - MySQL server has gone away"

Tags: mysql

I have MySQL Community Server 5.6.16 running, I have a mysql dump file of size 290MB,

and I have the following **my.ini** settings

```
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 60000000
max_allowed_packet = 8000000000M
```

When i try to restore the database from the dump file, I get error below

```
#2006 - MySQL server has gone away
```

How to resolve this error.

```
  RAM Size: 3.00 GB

    my.ini 
    ----------------
    key_buffer = 16M
    max_allowed_packet = 1M
    sort_buffer_size = 512K
    net_buffer_length = 8K
    read_buffer_size = 256K
    read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
    myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M


    innodb_buffer_pool_size = 16M
    innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 2M
    ## Set .._log_file_size to 25 % of buffer pool size
    innodb_log_file_size = 5M
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
    innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 60000000
```

[my.ini file download link](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B3uU23D89jnGWjJvOXhUV1ZtR3M/edit?usp=drive_web)

Comment: Did you check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away
and don't forget to restart your server after making changes to my.ini

Comment: let us know your server RAM and it will be help full if you share configuration file details specially innodb_buffer_pool_size and key_buffer_size...You can also check after changing max_allowed_packet = 64M.

Comment: @ZafarMalik, please see my edit and also i have given the link to my.ini file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change as per below:

```
max_allowed_packet = 64M
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1536M
```

Also add below lines same as given at the end of your ini file.

```
[mysqldump]
quick     ##it is already there in your file.
max_allowed_packet = 80000M # change it to 64M as this is more than your total memory.
```

After these changes restart mysql and check now.

If still getting error then share todays error logs from your error log file.

Comment: Main problem seems memory allocated to max_allowed_packet in mysqldump section which is more than total memory...

Comment: It was not accepting innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1536M, then changed to innodb_buffer_pool_size = 1000M,  its working fine now