# mysql crashes when alter table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using mysql version 6.1.4 and windows 7

I have an empty table where I want to drop a column and a foreign key. When I try to apply the changes the workbench crashes and when I try to stop Mysql it returns a error

```
ERROR 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query
SQL Statement:
ALTER TABLE `teste_db`.`search_products` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `product_id_id_refs_id_aa2f4dab`   

ERROR: Error when running failback script. Details follow.

ERROR 2006: MySQL server has gone away
```

I have looked around a lot and could not find any clue...

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: This post might help you. Seems to be a similar problem to yours.     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: Thanks!! Worked perfectly!!

Comment: Actually its weird... it worked for the original table that I wanted to modify and also alowed me to create a table that I could not before. But I am having the same problem to change the table I have just created... for the tables that existed before the my.ini file update it is now OK... any ideas on what might be going on?

Comment: Sorry-not sure what's causing that. Glad the first thing worked for you thou!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the steps , If you dont

1. If it is a MyISAM Table repair it first and check table .
2. Where as it is a empty table , check if any index present delete that,

Try then , if still not work

Please paste your table structure , Table Engine name.