# #2006 - MySQL server has gone away in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I try to import the excel showing error message.how to set max_allowed_packet in XAMPP. kindly share folders name and file name.

Comment: I'm trying to import a Excel CSV file into  my database.but it failed and shows "#2006 - MySQL server has gone away"

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: how to change set max_allowed_packet in xampp..? send file path also..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the value on this file `C:/xampp/mysql/bin/my.cnf` using notepad or any other text editor. Increase **max_allowed_packet** as needed

your file might look like this,

[image]

Restart mysql service

[image]