# Yii 1 console app Error MySQL gone away. it is Yii app

Tags: php, mysql, yii

I developing yii 1 console app. and for a long time runnning job sometime I got the error which says "2006 MySQL server has gone away"

I tried a couple of solution like change autoConnect properties of CDbConnection in main.php configuration file to false. However, it does not help.

Has anyone encountered this error before please share with me your solution.

Thanks

Nathan

Comment: did you try changing the `db` config `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: both are not possible solutions :(