# PDO connection error - server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, wamp

I'm using WAMP and I have an error message when trying to connect by using PDO 
the error message is:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away

I searched the internet and changed some things in `my.ini` file with max_allowed_packet and it doesn't work

what should I do? I'm new with everything so if you can write a detail explanation for beginners it will be awsome

Comment: The first thing you should do, is go read [ask].

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250453/how-to-solve-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away