# Symfony 3 : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away during update schema

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine, symfony-3.4

Since this morning every time i try update the schema of my database en symfony thanks to this command : `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force`. I receive 4 errors, you can see the output below :

```
In AbstractMySQLDriver.php line 126:
An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away  
                                                                                  

In PDOConnection.php line 50:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away  
                                                 

In PDOConnection.php line 46:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away  
                                                 

In PDOConnection.php line 46:
PDO::__construct(): Unexpected server respose while doing caching_sha2 auth: 109
```

Since yesterday i changed nothing.

This is my **parameter.yml**  :

```
parameters:
  database_host: 127.0.0.1
  database_port: 3306
  database_name: theatreP
  database_user: root
  database_password: ~
  mailer_transport: gmail
  mailer_host: 127.0.0.1
  mailer_user: %mon_mail%
  mailer_password: %psw%
  secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt`
```

I also check timeout with `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES LIKE '%timeout';` :

`+-----------------------------------+----------+ | Variable_name                     | Value    | +-----------------------------------+----------+ | connect_timeout                   | 10       | | delayed_insert_timeout            | 300      | | have_statement_timeout            | YES      | | innodb_flush_log_at_timeout       | 1        | | innodb_lock_wait_timeout          | 50       | | innodb_rollback_on_timeout        | OFF      | | interactive_timeout               | 28800    | | lock_wait_timeout                 | 31536000 | | mysqlx_connect_timeout            | 30       | | mysqlx_idle_worker_thread_timeout | 60       | | mysqlx_interactive_timeout        | 28800    | | mysqlx_port_open_timeout          | 0        | | mysqlx_read_timeout               | 30       | | mysqlx_wait_timeout               | 28800    | | mysqlx_write_timeout              | 60       | | net_read_timeout                  | 30       | | net_write_timeout                 | 60       | | rpl_stop_slave_timeout            | 31536000 | | slave_net_timeout                 | 60       | | wait_timeout                      | 28800    | +-----------------------------------+----------+`

I try to change value **wait_timeout** && **interactive_timeout** but i did not find the file to modify

I'm on Mac Os : **10.13.6 (High Sierra)**

---

Mysql :**8.0.12 for osx10.13 on x86_64 (Homebrew)** 
Php : **7.1.20** 
Node : **v8.12.0** 
npm : **6.4.1**

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250453/how-to-solve-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: In `/usr/local/etc/my.cnf` i changed value highest than default or lowest but the error is still there. I even uninstall and install again mysql 4 times today.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had to modify the mysql user to be identified with "caching_sha2_password":

```
CREATE USER 'db_user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'user_password';

ALTER USER `db_user`@`localhost` IDENTIFIED WITH caching_sha2_password BY 'user_password';

GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydatabase.* TO 'db_user'@'localhost';
```