# Laravel Migrate Cant connect to MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-valet

I have installed a fresh Laravel project (`5.7.5`) on my Mac (`10.13.6`).

I have installed mysql (8.0.12) with `brew install mysql` and the laravel project with the `laravel create laraveltest` command.

Laravel is running in the Valet environment (2.1.1).

I can connect to the Mysql server with the Sequel Pro client (127.0.0.0, root with no password) and also by the command line `mysql -uroot`.

I can create a database `create database laraveltest` and use the database `use laraveltest` but when I try migrating the database `php artisan migrate` i get an error:

> 'PDOException  : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away')

So it seems that Laravel can't connect to my `mysql` server.

My .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laraveltest
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

I tried uninstalling/installing mysql. restarting the computer. deleting/creating the laravel project. same error.

Any ideas what I can try to resolve this?

Comment: *MySQL server has gone away* means that the connection was made but then something wrong happened with a query that made the server drop the connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to solve General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250453/how-to-solve-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Answer (score -1):

input your root password of your php admin i  think you do have a password to root php admin right ? DB_PASSWORD="yourpassword"

Comment: the command 'mysql -uroot' works just fine, without password.