# How to share the DB in LAN network for access it?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 pcs connected to LAN.
Want to access the DB one of them. i can see the DB from entering URL "ipAddress:port/phpmyadmin".
But, when firing the queries i am unable to reach that DB or that pc i don't know?
In xampp "httpd.conf" file has also changed ServerName to below

```
`ServerName ip_address:8080`
```

And in xampp "httpd-xampp.conf" file i have made below changes to expose PHPmyadmin

```
`<Directory "C:/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
    AllowOverride AuthConfig
    Require all granted
    ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</Directory>`
```

I am getting this ERROR :

```
'Illuminate\Database\QueryException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away'
```

I have configured my DB in laravel like this ".env" file

```
`
 DB_HOST=ip_address_of_another_pc
 DB_PORT=3306
 DB_DATABASE=mychecklist
 DB_USERNAME=user
 DB_PASSWORD=pass`
```

The pcs have 2 different OS 1) windows(Db) and 2) Ubuntu 20.04(try to access db)

how to solve this?

Comment: For the error you're facing please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250453/how-to-solve-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away). Maybe of some help to you.