# PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in C:\..\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapte r.php:193

Tags: php, mysql, migration

whenever I try to create migrations for a large database with this command `./bin/cake migration migrate`

At first it starts migrating normally and then I receive this error

> PDOException:
> SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away in C:\Users\Yasmine Daly\Downloads\ES-189\EstimateV2\vendor\robmorgan\phinx\src\Phinx\Db\Adapter\PdoAdapter.php:193

and as a result it only adds 99 tables in my database ( it should be 165)
even if I try to import it manually from phpmyadmin I get this notification **"You probably tried to upload a file that is too large. Please refer to documentation for a workaround for this limit."**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve General error: 2006 MySQL server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33250453/how-to-solve-general-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: Not really. I tried setting the wait_timeout and interactive_timeout to 28800 before posting my question and it didn't work.