# Possible reasons for failing MySQL insert query after video upload

Tags: php, mysql, video, pdo, insert

I need some advice where to look for possible reasons for the issue below.

I am running an PHP script for video upload. Video uploads successfully on the server each time. After I do `move_uploaded_file` from the temp folder to the new folder I have the following code:

```
$sql_insrt  = "INSERT INTO tbl_videos SET
               video_name       = 'name1',
               v_id             = '12'";
$rs_insrt   = $db -> Execute($sql_insrt);
```

Now for small video files (1~5MB) the `$rs_insrt` query executes successfully without any issue.
However, when I try to upload a larger video (20MB for example), the `$rs_insrt` does not get executed. The video file is uploaded in the new folder (as it should) and the `$sql_insrt` query is correct but the insert query does not go trough.

Do you guys have any idea why this could be?

I have the following configuration in php.ini so I don't think this is the problem:

```
max_execution_time = 300 
max_file_uploads = 20
max_input_nesting_level = 64 
max_input_time = -1
max_input_vars = 1000
memory_limit = 128M
post_max_size = 100M
upload_max_filesize = 100M
```

Comment: do you check for db errors at all?

Comment: sounds like you're storing that as a BLOB and may have exceeded its length. Try LONGBLOB. This is a longshot in the dark, since we don't know how you're storing it, nor a db schema.

Comment: @Fred-ii- says he is storeing a file

Comment: @Dagon I ran out of ammo. My longshot seems to have run short.

Comment: @Dragon, thanks for the idea - the MySQL error I got is `MySQL server has gone away`.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html

Comment: i always hope that checking for errors is the idea to have before asking strangers on the interweb, but that's just me :p

Comment: Also maybe you find this useful: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.ping.php and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: basically: MySQL got bored waiting, up its timeout limit

Comment: @Dagon, you are right again, it just did not occur to me to check for MySQL errors, I guess i am too tired now...I think this will be all for tonight :)

Comment: @Kostas Mitsarakis, thanks for the resources i will check them tomorrow on fresh mind :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I have finally figured it out. The MySQL version got upgraded and the wait_timeout has been set to 20 sec. Hence the error.

The max allowed value by the hosting provider for wait_timeout is 90 sec - not good enough for my needs so I found a workaround.

I am checking for existing connection and if none, I am closing and then opening new one (example below for ADOdb):

```
if (!mysql_ping($db)) {
   $db->Close();                        
   $db = ADONewConnection('mysqli');
   $db->Connect('host','user','pass','name') or die("Database not found!");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try chunked file upload. I think you have a problem with timeout.
When your upload has finished so you can run your mysql statements.

https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Chunked-file-uploads