# How to configure Magmi after installation?

Tags: magento, magmi

We are using Magento 1.9 & Magmi `magmi_full_0.7.19a` version.

I want to know how to configure Magmi after installation.

I saw: `Configure current profile`, here i want to know what values need to give below

1)Copy Selected Profile to:

2)CSV import mode - local or remote ?

3)CSVs base directory

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **"Copy Selected Profile to"** means that you can create a carbon-copy of the currently loaded profile you're running (Default for example). If you enter a name in the box next it and click the button, it will duplicate what's currently loaded. You can create as many profiles as you like - if you have a profile that you just want to run for images for example, you can check the preferences and save the CSV applicable to this and save it. It'll save you having to re-check options every time.
2. **Local / Remote** - Depends whether the CSV you want to run is located on your own (local) server or elsewhere.
3. **Base Dir - Further to point 2**,  if you've added the CSV to your `var/import`  folder (which you should've), leave this as Local. It simply tell Magmi where to look on your server for the import file you want to run. If you put the file in a folder "`testfolder/subfolder`", you'd enter that as the base directory.

Comment: @spylh9999ggr Could be a CSV data issue or any number of things. What is the error saying?

Comment: `SQLSTATE[HY000] [2006] MySQL server has gone away -` is error

Comment: @spylh9999ggr thats a separate issue altogether - check this thread out which may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: okay, but in site i never faced this issue. its didplaying "no csv files found" on magmi page, but still i  "run import " , is it because of that reason also ?

Comment: i placed a csv file under var/import folder .

but still i am getting message : No csv files found i : http://prnt.sc/av0i67 ?

Comment: @spylh9999ggr Make sure Magmi is looking in the right server path. Go to Configuration from the top tabs and under Magento, see if you need to go up a level or two in "Filesystem Path to magento directory:". Try adding in `../` or `../../`. The Magmi installation looks like its in a subfolder on your server.

Comment: we installed magmi in root directory : http://prnt.sc/av0pty & http://prnt.sc/av0pw1

Comment: @spylh9999ggr Yes but I can see from your first screenshot that MAgmi is looking in the wrong folder, you need to go up a level... Try adding `../var/import` as your CSV base directory then. If that doesn't find the CSV's try `../../var/import`, if that doesn't work, try `../../../var/import`. Remember to save profile every time you change CSV base dir too.

Comment: i gave this : `/4/em0113-full-package/var/import` in `CSVs base directory`  :  http://prnt.sc/av0tev  but still same issue is there.

Comment: when i empty the input box value of "CSVs base directory" , it worked for me , thanks a lot.