# ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 3838122: MySQL server has gone away

Tags: php, mysql

I have database file of 2.5gb , i imported through terminal but it gets error

```
   ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 3838122: MySQL server has gone away
```

I changed max_allowed_packet=64M but no change.How to do this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: what duplicate @nawin

Comment: yes, check the post and increase `max_allowed_packet=1073741824;`