# ERROR 2006 mysql

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to make an attachment of a very large value, this value has 2530000 characters. But I'm throwing an error:

> ERROR 2006 (HY000) at line 867015: MySQL server has gone away

I tried :

```
max_allowed_packet=3562M
```

`sql_mode = ""`

```
innodb_buffer_pool_size = 256M
```

`innodb_additional_mem_pool_size = 10M`

```
 innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 180
```

Comment: I think you can find the answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away

Comment: @ecp, no, they offer the solution I indicated above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe:

`wait_timeout=28800
interactive_timeout = 28800
max_allowed_packet=16M`

Check this, maybe could help:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gone-away.html