# MySQL server has gone away upon changes

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to import ~1GB .sql file which contains `INSERTS`. I'm using following command to do so: `mysql -u root -p databae < database.sql` but I keep receiving an error `MySQL server has gone away`.

I've tried increasing `max_allowed_packet` to 64M but no change.

Comment: This may be a duplicate of ["MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Comment: @mattmatters Also, please post last 400 lines of your error.log after an incident, please.