# MySQL server has gone away , ( ERROR 2006 ) on Windows 10

Tags: php, mysql

The error am facing

> MySQL server has gone away , ( ERROR2006 )

on Windows 10 but the same code and `WAMPServer` version on **Windows 7** it works correct, please, what will be the problem? I have checked the `allowed_packet_size` = 8,16,32,64,128,512 but it doesn't change anything the problem continues.
Thanks for your help...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)

Answer (score 0):

you can do

1. Server timed out and closed the connection. To fix, check that
   wait_timeout mysql variable in your my.cnf configuration file is
   large enough.

2.You may also need to increase the innodb_log_file_size mysql variable in your my.cnf configuration to for example 128MB or higher.

3.Server dropped an incorrect or too large packet. If mysqld gets a packet that is too large or incorrect, it assumes that something
    has gone wrong with the client and closes the connection. To fix,
    you can increase the maximal packet size limit max_allowed_packet in
    my.cnf file, eg. set max_allowed_packet = 128M, then restart your
    MySQL server: sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart