# MySQL server has gone away and can't connect to local MySQL server from Rails application

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I have a Rails application which has a huge database. It uses the gem `mysql2` to connect to `MySQL`. It was working fine until yesterday. Today when I started the application I am getting these errors while trying to connect to that specific database.

```
ERROR 2006 (HY000): MySQL server has gone away
No connection. Trying to reconnect...
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (111)
ERROR: 
Can't connect to the server
```

Mysql connection is established to other databases well but not to this one database. It was perfectly fine even with this database until yesterday. Why did it change suddenly?

I also checked and made changes as per the answer in this link:
[MySQL error 2006: mysql server has gone away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7942154/mysql-error-2006-mysql-server-has-gone-away)
but I am still getting the same error. How can I rectify this error?

Comment: Probably system mysql has crashed. try to login your mysql

Comment: I logged into `mysql` and checked it. When I `use some_other_database` it works fine but when I `use this_database` I get the above error. After that I cannot `use some_other_database`, it shows the same error. I should logout of mysql and then login again to `use some_other_database`.

Comment: Did you check mysql logs? Looks like database is damaged or you're hitting some mysql bug

Comment: Yes. I checked `error.log` file. It showed database is corrupted. I could not delete database from the usual sql command. I had to delete the database folder manually and then again ran `bin/rake db:setup`. But why did it happen like that? I did not change anything in the code or database.